# Java Play FrameWork 2.3 return streamed Json using jackson

Tags: java, json, playframework, stream, jackson

Is there a way I can stream Json in my API response?

I understand how I can read and write a json file using jackson library from this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/

But now in play framework, how can stream my response or in other words return what in my API intead of `return ok();`?

Comment: Is it a file with a json string you want to stream, or is it just a json? Do you use POJOs to represent json data?

Comment: it's just a json , but if i'm not wrong you should treat json as a file to stream it...and yes i use pojos

Comment: What `PlayFramework` version do you use?

Comment: Maybe chunked responses? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Play's chunked responses](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaStream)?

In your controller you would have an action something on this line:

```
public Result chunkedJson() {
    return ok(readJsonChunks());
}
```

And in the `readJsonChunks` method you actually create the Chunks:

```
public static Chunks<String> readJsonChunks() {
    Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() {

        @Override
        public void onReady(play.mvc.Results.Chunks.Out<String> out) {
            JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
            try {
                // Read from file
                JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser(new File("c:\\user.json"));

                // Loop until token equal to "}"
                while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                    // Write all your JSON stuff into out, e.g. with
                    String text = jParser.getText();
                    out.write(text);
                }

                jParser.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                out.write("Couldn't open file c:\\user.json");
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    };
    return chunks;
}
```

I've never tried this particular code (especially I've never used JsonFactory.createJsonParser - it seems to be deprecated) but I use something similar to send log files from a server to a client.

(I'm working with Play 2.2.3)

Comment: i will be checking it out soon